# Dhall - map on record field

Tags: functor, dhall

I have a type

```
let Resource = \(a : Type) ->
  { name : Text
  , type : Text
  , properties : a
  }
```

and a function `foo : InstanceTemplateProperties -> Properties`.

I need to create a function `Resource InstanceTemplateProperties -> Resource Properties`.

I could write it as

```
\(p : Resource InstanceTemplateProperties) ->
  { name = p.name
  , type = p.type
  , properties = foo p.properties
  } : Resource Properties
```

but it looks really cumbersome. Is there an easier and more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Just using a short, generic name like `p` instead of `instanceTemplateProperties` would be a good start.

Comment: @chepner voilà, is it better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `//` to merge the updated properties into the original.

```
(\p : Resource InstanceTemplateProperties) ->
  p // {properties = foo p.properties)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit; I obviously misremembered the operator, and I think I misread the Unicode operator for a single ASCII `/` without seeing the ASCII equivalent.